# Which SDK to use WinUI3 or UWP for a native windows app?

Tags: windows, uwp, native, winui-3

For building a native windows app which can launch multiple web applications in a webview , i have tried a poc using WinUI3 .Main usecase for this is usb peripheral integrations from the webapps loaded in webview and Single Sign On . Reading more on microsoft documentation , i see some features not supported and some slowness compared to UWP. Do i need to go with UWP for a new app or is the recommendation to go with WInUI3 for a new app development .

Supported Feature List Doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/what-is-supported

Can see WebAuthenticationBroker also in not supported list .
Any guidance on what sdk to use . UWP or WinUI3

Comment: UWP has been clearly deprecated by Microsoft. As for the list of what's supported and what works, the doc between UWP and WinUI3 is quite broken overall and sometimes not fully up to date, so the best is to try. The roadmap for WinUI3 is not up to date either. Although WinUI3 doesn't look 100% good, I'd bet on it, and hopefully they will improve all that (they did over time). Otherwise,  you can start with UWP, it won't go away soon even if it doesn't evolve, and move back later on WinUI3 as source code is very similar between the two

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, but this is clearly misinformation. Currently Microsoft upgrades it's own stock apps to UWP and WinUI 2 in Windows 11. They also mentioned one app written in WinUI 3 during community call.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov - clearly you don't understand what I said. UWP (and so WinUI2) is officially deprecated (for ex: https://www.thurrott.com/dev/258377/microsoft-officially-deprecates-uwp). That doesn't mean it will disappear suddently or everyone will drop maintenance of existing products. WinUI3 is definitely the upgrade path to UWP.

Comment: @SimonMourier Clearly thurrott.com is not an official source and by refering to it, you are spreading misleading information.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov - Please try to answer questions on this site instead of being an pain to others https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/1615

Comment: @SimonMourier Even the GitHub article you referenced in your last comment directly says: "WinUI 2.x and the Windows SDK will continue to support UWP project types, including bug, reliability, and security fixes. In Windows, we use UWP project types for several of our own Windows apps." So, who is trolling here, you or me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinUI3 is the new technology for Windows Desktop. Although it is not perfect now, but it will be improved. Currently, not all the WinRT APIs are able to be used in WinUI3 apps, but you could use win32 APIs to achieve what you want. So I'd suggest you use WinUI if you are familiar with win32 API can you use win32 API to bypass the limitations.

Compared to WinUI3, UWP is more stable. UWP could use all the WinRT APIs. But some features on UWP are not up to date. For example, some features from WebView2 controls are missing on UWP but available on WinUI like print. Another thing is that UWP apps have limitations like system isolation for accessing local files and local network resources.